# Is it possible to clone a file descriptor?

Tags: linux, file, file-descriptor

Is it possible to clone a file descriptor? I know about `dup`, but I'd like to have a file descriptor which has a separate state (position), as if I opened the same file again, with the same flags (the problem with re-opening is that a) I have to store file path, which is not needed currently in my code and b) If the file has been deleted, I cannot re-open it).

If it is not possible, then my idea is to use `dup`, and `pread`/`pwrite`, so I manage file position myself. Are there any drawbacks of this idea?

Comment: Doesn't `dup2` clone a file descriptor?

Comment: @jww It does, but the descriptors are indistinguishable. Reads and writes using one update the file position for the other as well.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a single library function or system call that will do what you want on Linux. But you can do the following:

1. Use `readlink(3)` or `realpath(3)` on the file `/proc/self/fd/<X>`, where `<X>` is the file descriptor you want to duplicate. This returns the full path to the file in question.
2. Call `open(2)` to get a brand new descriptor for that file.
3. Use second file descriptor however you want. Its `read(2)`s and `write(2)`s are independent.

This gets around your concern about *storing* the file path, by just getting it dynamically when needed.

I don't understand your second point, though, the one about deleting the file. If *this* process deletes the file, why would you want to create a duplicate descriptor for it? Regardless, if either this or another process deletes the file, then the file is still accessible until the file descriptor itself is closed anyway. Doing the duplication as I described above should be valid until *every* open descriptor referring to the file is closed. (Although you won't be able to use the link `/proc/self/fd/<X>` if *this* process deletes the file *and* closes its descriptor. You'll need another way of recovering the filename from the file descriptor. But in that case, the question doesn't make much sense as you no longer have a valid descriptor to duplicate anyway!)

Also, creating a second, independent file descriptor seems like a bit of a strange design choice to me. I'd probably just go with `lseek(2)` + `read(2)` or `pread(2)`. I don't see any special drawbacks to that approach, other than needing to manage different file positions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The reason for the clone is that I have a class, which has an fd (actually, it is more complicated than that, but that's a basic setup), which is a zip file. And this class has an `open` function (it opens a file from the zip), which clones the `fd`, and returns a zip-decompressor object (which uses the cloned `fd`). And multiple (independent) files can be opened from a zip. So `lseek` doesn't work here, as I need separate position for each zip-stream. I thought that there's some system call, which will re-open the file for me. But it seems that there isn't any.